# Polymer - avoid reinventing the wheel

Tags: polymer, vaadin

Sorry if this is a generic question, but I have been given a task to develop a web application, and I'd like to use this opportunity to dive into and learn about Polymer (and maybe Vaadin components?).

I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel. But I'm a newbie regarding Polymer. So, given the following task, is there any approach and component that will make the developing quicker/smarter?

---

Create an application which will allow at least two users to log in simultaneously and manage items in categories. The categories should be in a hierarchy of potentially infinite depth. The items only require a label.

The users should be able to perform standard CRUD, plus if one user makes a change, the other user(s) should see the change (if appropriate) without manually refreshing their web browser.

---

How should I approach this with Polymer? 
Has anyone done anything similar?

I'm also open to Vaadin components if it helps.

Any help or guideline?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to start from an application template like [polymer3-webpack-starter](https://github.com/web-padawan/polymer3-webpack-starter) or [pwa-starter-kit](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit).

If you are looking to use Vaadin components like [vaadin-grid](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid), use [polymer3-webpack-starter](https://github.com/web-padawan/polymer3-webpack-starter) or one of the starters from the [vaadin.com/start](https://vaadin.com/start) page.

If you do not need an example specifically with Vaadin components, then [pwa-starter-kit](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit) would be a good starting point. Though it assumes familiarity with [redux](https://redux.js.org).

**Pro**: You can quickly get a running application that you can modify to your needs, and you do not have to set a project from scratch (build tool chain, module bundler, tests, configuration, etc - all of that is done already).

**Con**: Making modifications to the project setup won't be necessarily easy because at that point you *will* have to dive into the project setup that somebody has done for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Any idea regarding "if one user makes a change, the other user(s) should see the change (if appropriate) without manually refreshing their web browser". How should I approach this?

Comment: This sounds like you need a backend that supports pushing updates to the frontend. If you are building the backend of your app with Vaadin platform, check the [Server Push Configuration](https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-configuration.html) docs for details and examples. If you are using something else, you'll probably need to search for the key words like 'push' or 'live updates' in the docs.